# Can you change or swap out the Pokemon in a gym on Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The other day I put a Pokemon in a gym and was actually able to train him up a bit more while he was in the gym. Today I can not do anything with him. I was hoping to switch him out with another Pokemon.

Is there a way we can switch which Pokemon are in the gym?

Answer (score 8):

You can't swap a Pokémon with one of your own. You can however, under some conditions, swap your Pokémon with one at a friendly Gym. This is only possible when:

- The Gym is at the maximum level of 10
- All places in the Gym are occupied (10 Pokémon)
- You don't already have a Pokémon at the Gym
- The Pokémon you want to add has a higher CP value than the lowest

In that case, the Pokémon with the lowest CP value will be kicked out of the Gym and is returned to its owner. [Source (pg. 6)](https://imgur.com/gallery/iQNiY).

Comment: I have seen this situation in a number of allied gyms at 50k prestige that i have visited, but i do not get any button to choose to swap. When will the button be available? do you have to take it over 50k prestige?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. All Pokemon are stuck in the respected gym until someone in an opposing faction comes and either knocks your pokemon out(if its a lower tier of the gym) or captures the gym outright.